# Export everything from Python module or import everything from module

Tags: python, python-3.x

This may be well written somewhere on the internet (even on SO) but I could not find it.

---

Suppose I have a Python project structure like the following

```
mymodule
|—-__init__.py
|—-a.py
|—-b.py
|—-c.py
main.py
```

Now, I want to import in `main.py` everything from `mymodule`, meaning I want to be able to do the following:

```py
import mymodule

mymodule.a.something()
mymodule.b.something_else()
```

I do not want to do the following:

```py
import mymodule.a
import mymodule.b
import mymodule.c
```

How can I achieve this? In JS ES6, you would create a file `mymodule.js` for example, in which you would import everything that you want to export, and then export it. Is there something similar possible in Python?

Comment: You need to understand, when you `import mymodule` it is essentially equivalent to importing the module in `mymodule/__init__.py`. So, if you want to be able to use other names there, you need to import those *other modules* in there

Comment: Oh, you are right! I forgot how imports work in Python, was a long time I was doing something concrete in it. I supposed I would need to import it in __init__.py and then somehow export, but in Python imports of one file are available to all importers of that file as well.

Comment: "and somehow export it" there really is no such thing. Like you stated, if there is a name available in a module, well, *then it's available in the module*. Python != JS

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, if you want, you can write an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, when importing a module you are essentially importing its `__init__.py` file.
The correct way to handle this is to import whatever you need inside `mymodule/__init__.py`, and then all those imports will be available to whoever imports `mymodule`.